# Pegar a apresentar últimos caracteres de URL

Tags: php

Preciso pegar os últimos 14 caracteres de uma relação de urls dentro de um .txt

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.site.com.br/relacao.txt');
```

Dentro de relacao.txt tenho:

```
www.site.com.br/aluno/s/francisco-augusto/11111111111111
www.site.com.br/aluno/s/francisco-fernandes/11111111111112
www.site.com.br/aluno/s/francisco-ocario/11111111111113
www.site.com.br/aluno/s/giselia-augusto/11111111111114
www.site.com.br/aluno/s/giselia-fernandes/11111111111115

Etc.. (várias outras)
```

E gostaria de apresentar da seguinte forma: (apenas com os últimos números)

```
11111111111111
11111111111112
11111111111113
11111111111114
11111111111115

Etc...
```

Eu já tentei de diversas formas.

```
$url = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", " ", $url);
```

Mas o resultado fica da seguinte forma:

`11111111111111 11111111111112 1111111111113 11111111111114 etc`.

Preciso que cada número fique em uma linha.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit

Como visto, seu resultado não é como escrito na pergunta, pois você está fazendo errada a leitura do arquivo.

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
$arq = file("url.txt");
foreach($arq as $linha){
   echo buscaFinal($linha);
   echo '<br>';
}

function buscaFinal($linha) {
   $var = substr($linha,(strlen($linha)-14),strlen($linha));
   return $var;
}
```

---

Você pode usar o `substr` com `strlen`:

```
$txt = "www.site.com.br/aluno/s/giselia-augusto/11111111111114";
$var = substr($txt,(strlen($txt)-14),strlen($txt));
echo $var;
```

Saída: `11111111111114`

*(obs: você colocou 12 caracteres, mas no exemplo tem 14)*

Para dar a quebra de linha, pode usar o `php_eol`, `echo <br>`, `echo '\n'`, aí depende se irá imprimir no arquivo, na página, etc

```
function buscaFinal($linha) {
  $var = substr($linha,(strlen($linha)-14),strlen($linha));
  echo $var;
  echo '<br>';
}
```

---

Outra forma caso padrão as barras "/"

Você pode usar o `explode`:

```
$txt = "www.site.com.br/aluno/s/giselia-fernandes/11111111111115";
$var = explode("/", $txt);
echo $var[4];
```

Saída: `11111111111115`

---

Documentações:

[explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)

[substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)

[strlen](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strlen.php)

[Constantes Pré-definidas](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.constants.php)

Comment: function buscaFinal($linha) {
  $var = substr($linha,(strlen($linha)-14),strlen($linha));
  echo $var;
  php_eol;
}

$url = file_get_contents('https://www.site.com.br/relacao.txt');
$numero = buscaFinal($url);
echo $numero;

Retorna apenas o primeiro número da relação.

Comment: Mas aí você tem que ler o `txt` e ir jogando a linha que está lendo. Considerei que você já está lendo seu `txt`. Clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/315638/edit) na sua pergunta e poste todo seu código, assim consigo fazer o exemplo nele.

Comment: Pois então, eu tenho uma relacao.txt com milhares de urls dentro. (como dito na pergunta) eu preciso acessar o relacao.txt pegar todas as urls e então imprimir APENAS os últimos 14 caracteres. por linha (como mencionado na pergunta)

Comment: Mas você diz "Mas o resultado fica da seguinte forma:", então entende-se que você já está acessando o txt e mandando imprimir correto? Poste então a parte que faz a leitura do txt, e o loop que você usa para imprimir o conteúdo. Não é o conteúdo do txt que é para postar.

Comment: acho que não entendi... 
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.site.com.br/relacao.txt'); // aqui eu acesso o conteúdo certo?
se eu der o echo em $url eu tenho: www.site.com.br/aluno/s/francisco-augusto/11111111111111 (e diversas outras urls) eu preciso que: ao imprimir o resultado ele apenas mostre (de todas as urls) os 14 últimos números.

Comment: Então o seu retorno não é `11111111111111 11111111111112 1111111111113 11111111111114` como está na pergunta. Não é assim que usa o `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Irei abrir um chat caso precise continuar a questão, pois já estendeu muito os comentários.